# Making SEO friendly forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html, seo

I am wondering if it is possible to change the way forms submit data without the use of JS or perhaps in a search engine friendly way

I have two separate very basic forms. The first contains a dropdown menu allowing you to pick a subject. The other serves the exact same purpose, it only allows you to type the subject in a text box (and make use of autocomplete) rather than picking it up from the long list.

Currently both forms submit the data in a GET method, so a basic submission for the same choice would result in the following URL :

http://example.com/subject/?text=XXXXXX

(I am using .htaccess to rewrite /subject to an actual php script...)

What i am trying to do is actually make the URL look like this instead:

http://example.com/subject/XXXXXX

Currently my .htaccess will recognize both URLs with no problem, i am just curious to know if there is a way to make forms submit using the second method with no JS or any SE friendly method

Comment: Why should search engines fill out your forms?

Comment: i don't want them to fill the form :D i mainly want them to recognize the available choices in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a list of choices with all the urls and if js is disabled (SE) you show this list (and hide the form). If js is enabled you show the form.

You can hide the form in css and set it to visible using js. Or generate the whole form using js.

Comment: wow i don't know how i missed that ! Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1):

To send the form, all http clients (both browsers and SEs, although I don't know if SEs fill & send forms) will construct the name=value pairs. You can change that by touching the action attribute of the form (and maybe removing the variables before sending it), but that of course requires Javascript.

Without JS, you can't change it because that is just how forms have to be sent.

If you want to index a search engine friendly URL, I think your best choice is to redirect with .htaccess directives, but that can only happen after you receive the parameterized URL.

Answer (score 0):

Search engine spiders won't submit forms. You have to put the items you want from the list somewhere else in the page where the spider will find them - e.g. in a paragraph above the combo box. You could put them in the meta description or keyword tag but only if they are actually important - google will penalise your ranking if it decides you are trying to ram too much optimisation into the page.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, The most optimal solution is to add a small parser script that fixes the URL format, and make a 302 redirection to the new link.

In other words, supposing that the form submitted the following link:

```
http://example.com/subject/?text=XXXXXX
```

The PHP script would receive the link, replace the part: ?text=XXXXXX with XXXXXX, and redirect the User to the new page.

This solution would save us the .htaccess complexity and allow us more flexibility in maintaining the forms in the future.